# SharePoint 2013 list - column indexes, list threshold limit, REST api

Tags: sharepoint

We have indexed a couple of columns in SharePoint 2013 lists and these columns are used in $filter in REST api. The query stops working when the list crosses its threshold limit. Isn't the index meant to have columns queried and filtered no matter what the data size is in the list? Can someone throw any light on this?

Comment: Check this thread https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/210391/sharepoint-list-5000-item-threshold-with-indexed-column-confusion

Comment: Sorry had to put this on-hold as we had some other issues to address. At the moment we have indexed all the respective columns (single line, lookup, choice) that would be a part of the query filter and full crawl was run. We still get a threshold limit exception. Any ideas or alternatives?

Comment: To add to that the $top is set to fetch 200 rows

Comment: Update - $filter works fine for ID and Title columns but choice and lookup columns throws a threshold limit exception